# UITextField identifier to resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working in an iPhone project, and I have a UITableView where each cell has a UITextField to edit the information. The problem is, if a touch the TextField the Keyboard will be shown and if a click on back button of navigation controller, I need to resign the keyboard and save the new information. My idea was to save in a NSMutableDictionary the PlaceHolder of the textfield as key and value is the indexPath of it. I have another NSMutableDictionary where I save as key the UITextField and Value IndexPath. The reason to do this is, that the method textFieldDidEndEdition receive UITextField as parameter and I need to know what field was pressed to update my database.

I hope to be clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Key Value Observing (KVO) on the `text` property of `UITextField` to automatically update your model when it's value changes?

See [Apple's Key Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) for more information.